# Which one of these is the phase 1?

Tags: power, motor, grounding, three-phase

Which one of these is the phase 1? And why isn't there a neutral wire at all? The cable is Chinese. The device it powers is a 3-phase motor that powers hydraulics. I am sorry for asking this question here, but I don't know a better place. I have never come across this kind of color code. There is a connection between the black and the grey cable resistance is 230 ohms. [image: Cable]

To put my question in a more technical way:

is it possible, from just the view on the colored wires in the motor cable, to deduct the internal design of the motor? What if I measured the DC resistances between all these four wires with a simple multimeter?

Comment: The best (only) place to ask, would be the manufacturer. I assume there is no documentation.

Comment: If it doesn't have a neutral wire it's possible it's a 'delta' connection. There really isn't a 'phase one' just 'Yellow Red Blue' or ' Brown Blue Black' (though your country colour code may vary). The fourth wire is perhaps a ground. Try testing for continuity on each wire and the metal casing of the motor.

Comment: This site does not provide support for the use of products, particularly not products for which no information from the rating plate or user manual is provided. Wire color codes can not be relied upon. I have voted to close the question.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. @CharleCowie Yeah I knew that I shouldn't ask this here I just wanted a fast answer and also as the manufactures doesn't understand English.

Comment: See what the resistance is between The green wire and the metal case of the motor.  Green usually means ground

Comment: @SimeonR It does not matter if the motor windings are connected Star or Delta. The 3-phase windings are symmetrical, and no neutral wire is needed.

Comment: @Oneprime you could also ohm out the motor if you knew how many windings and what configuration they are in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just hook it up. if the motor runs in the wrong direction, just reverse 2 of the phases

Comment: I did hook up the motor and found out that the red cable was the second phase, black the first and grey the third.

Comment: @Oneprime Great, you solved your problem. But note that you might as well call Red=L1, Grey=L2, Black=L3, or: Grey=L1, Black=L2, Red=L3, because the motor will run in the exact same direction. If you are looking at all possibilities, you have three choices of color for L1, then two for L2, and one left for L3, multiply, 3*2*1 = 6 possibilities. Your connection plus mine two above makes three, leaves the other three possibilities will make the motor run the other direction.

Comment: Thank you for the information

Comment: @Oneprime No problem, was fun to figure this out for myself. If you wish, you may upvote my comment. Please be generous and also upvote other answers and comments that people took time to write for you, if you find those useful :-)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this is a standard [colour code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_wiring#Colour_code) it looks to me like we have `green`, `blue`, `red`, `black`. Three-phase motors will often not have a neutral.

We know that `green` is going to be a protective earth wire.

This leaves `blue`, `red`, and `black`. The United States of America and Canada each have these colours:

```
The United States of America:

 1. Black, 2. Red, 3. Blue

Canada:

 1. Red, 2. Black, 3. Blue
```

As mentioned to you, you won't know which is correct without consulting the manufacturer but I think you can take a fairly educated guess that one of these *is* correct. Also, @Rolan points out a great point. If you choose the wrong combination the motor will just run in reverse. Simply swap two phases to correct it.

Comment: Well, we can make an EDUCATED GUESS that Green is Ground, and it SHOULD be, but we don't actually KNOW that for sure. it came from China after all...

Comment: @JRaef Actually, from the photo, that wire is yellow-green. International for ground. If not, it cannot be sold in europe or the us. But don't take my word. Just measure that between that wire and the metal motor enclosure is just a few ohm. It should be "zero" ohm, but a) that is the ideal value, b) one ohm and less is hard to measure accurately with a simple multimeter, and c) not needed, as long as it is significantly lower than the resistance of the windings, and will blow up the fuse in case of internal short circuit.

Comment: As I said, it SHOULD be ground and if the motor came from anywhere else I would just make that leap of faith. But I have encountered several cheap Chinese items where they seemed to totally ignore international conventions for color coding, as if they just used whatever they had available at the moment.

Comment: @JRaef My comment was not meant to dispute yours, just to augment. After all, this forum is about engineering, and an engineer would resolve a dispute with a measurement, if possible. My comment is also an effort to get this question back from "Closed As Off Topic"